# mutation in both offspring in genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

should we do mutation in both offspring (in same place and with same probability)?
the following is the code I used for mutation in binary population. is it true?

```
rand2=randi(100);
   if rand2>=0 && rand2<=2
       mu1_point=randi(m);

       parent1(1,mu1_point)=abs(1-parent1(1,mu1_point));
       parent2(1,mu1_point)=abs(1-parent2(1,mu1_point));
   end
```

Comment: This highly depends on the application you have and we cannot state any general rule. However, as starting point it makes sense to mutate both childs.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code what exactly is going on. In general, it's usually good for there to be some chance of the offspring not mutating, and for them not to both mutate in the same way (you want to try a diversity of solutions)

Comment: so, did I make a mistake to have mutation in both offspring in the same way?

Comment: and one more question is: can we have mutation in only one gene of a chromosome(offspring)(as I have in the following code) ? or should we create random number as mutation rate for all gene in a chromosome?

Comment: If you are applying the same mutation to both offspring, then yes, that is probably a mistake. I can't actually tell from your code if that's what you are doing. Mutations should be random, so sometimes you might get them in only one gene of a chromosome, or sometimes you might get them in multiple genes, and sometimes you might not get a mutation at all.